# stl sort comparison class function

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector

I'd like to use stl sort with a class comparison function `greater` that uses `infoVec1` and `infoVec2` but I'm getting a compile error:

Here is the class header

```
class Compare{
    Compare();
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& infoVec1;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& infoVec2;


    public:

    bool greater(int one, int two);

    Compare(std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& info1,
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& info2);
};
```

I've initialized Compare in main like so:

```
Compare C = Compare(info1, info2);
```

And I'm trying to use great in main like:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), C.greater);
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
main.cpp:266: error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2852: note: candidates are: void std::sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _Compare = bool (Compare::*)(int, int)]
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

How could I fix this class so that `greater` will work with stl sort?

Comment: The comparison function should be a freestanding function or an function object.

Comment: vec is of type std::vector<int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to change the greater() method into operator()().

```
class Compare{
    Compare();
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& infoVec1;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& infoVec2;


    public:

    bool operator()(int one, int two) const;  // this is used automatically.

    Compare(std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& info1,
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >& info2);
};
```